# How to change specific div using #id>div>div but only one of the divs that are applicable are affected

Tags: css

How can you change the css of a specific div even if a bunch of parent divs do not have ids? You can do

```css
#someid>div>div>div>div>div
```

and I tried that, but it changes all the applicable divs at that level, not the one I want only. say there is ten divs that parent one div i want, and i use css like that to change the color. But there is another one of the same generation ( a sibling is it called) that also gets affected. **imortant:** there are no ids until that tenth one

Comment: if you can't apply an id or class to the element, use selectors such as `div:nth-of-child(3)`
It's hard to specify a solution without further information in your question

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you didn't share your code it's hard to find any solution. But Still if you're facing issue with CSS you can try inline CSS which will help you to achieve your goal. Inline CSS Like-

```
<div style="width:50%; text-align:center; justify-content:center;">Hello Josh</div>
```

In the above code ***style*** is inline CSS.

Comment: I can't use inline since the css I am making will be used as a stylesheet for an existing webpage, and basically all these reasons such as I can only input css on this platform if its in style tags since its not my webpage, I only edit parts of it. And if I edit one part, I can put style tags in that part which can let me change the rest of the webpage. JS would make things easy but the platform doesnt ALLOW script tags